# Map BERTopic topic IDs back to the training dataframe

Tags: python-3.x, nlp, bert-language-model, topic-modeling

I have trained a BERTopic model on a dataframe of length of 400k. I want to map the topics of each document in a new column inside the dataframe. I could do that by running a for loop on all the documents and do `topic_model.transform(doc)` on them. The only problem is, it takes more than a second to transform each document into its topic and it would take days for the whole dataset.

Is there a way to achieve this faster since I want to map the topics on the training data.

I tried:

```
topic_model = BERTopic()
topics, probs = topic_model.fit_transform(docs)
topic_model.reduce_topics(docs, nr_topics=200)

topics = []
for text in df.texts:
    tops = topic_model.transform(text)
    topics.append(tops)
df['topics'] = topics
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is no need to recalculate the topics as you already retrieved them when using `.fit_transform`. There, the `topics` that you retrieve are in the exact same order as the input documents. Therefore, you can perform the following:

```py
# The `topics` that you get here are in the exact same order as `docs`
# `topics[0]` belongs to `docs[0]`, `topics[1]` to `docs[1]`, etc.
topic_model = BERTopic()
topics, probs = topic_model.fit_transform(docs)
topic_model.reduce_topics(docs, nr_topics=200)

# When you used `.fit_transform`:
df = pd.DataFrame({"Document": docs, "Topic": topic})
```

For those using `.fit` instead of `.fit_transform`, you can also access the topics and their documents as follows:

```py
# When you used `.fit`:
df = pd.DataFrame({"Document": docs, "Topic": topic_model.topics_})
```

Comment: Great job on developing the package if you are the same Maarten

Answer (score 1):

From the [source code](https://github.com/MaartenGr/BERTopic/blob/master/bertopic/_bertopic.py#L367), the `transform()` function of the BERTopic class is able accept a list of documents  -- so you don't need to loop over your dataframe calling `transform()` multiple times for each document.

Secondly, [it seems](https://github.com/MaartenGr/BERTopic/blob/master/bertopic/_bertopic.py#L418) that if you don't pass your pre-trained document embeddings to the `transform()` function, `embeddings` will be set to `None` and you'll be calling [_extract_embeddings()](https://github.com/MaartenGr/BERTopic/blob/master/bertopic/_bertopic.py#L2223) every single time which is likely what is causing the poor performance. The solution is to pass the embeddings to your `transform()` call. In the dummy example shown below, this improves speed of classification of 1,000 documents by approx. 1,555x (68.43 vs 0.044 seconds).

### Example

```py
from bertopic import BERTopic
from sentence_transformers import SentenceTransformer
from sklearn.datasets import fetch_20newsgroups
import random
import pandas as pd

# Create dummy data
docs = fetch_20newsgroups(subset='all',  remove=('headers', 'footers', 'quotes'))['data']
random.seed(756)
training_docs = random.sample(docs, 1000)
testing_docs = random.sample(docs, 1000)

# Instantiate and fit topic model to training docs
sentence_model = SentenceTransformer("all-MiniLM-L6-v2")
embeddings = sentence_model.encode(training_docs, show_progress_bar=True)
topic_model = BERTopic().fit(training_docs, embeddings)
topic_model.reduce_topics(training_docs, nr_topics=5)  # Reduce num of topics, default = 20

# Determine topics on testing docs
topics, probs = topic_model.transform(testing_docs, embeddings)
# topics, probs = topic_model.transform(testing_docs)  # ~1,555x slower
df = pd.DataFrame({"docs": testing_docs, "topics": topics})
print(df)
print(topic_model.get_topic_info())
```